# Splitting csv into multiple files with header using awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, awk

I am attempting to split a csv file based on unique column values into multiple files using awk. I am able to split the csv successfully with `awk -F\, '{print > $2".csv"}' example.csv` however it is committing the header column from the new files.

For example:

```
example.csv

Color,Car,Make
Red,Kia,Spectra
Orange,Kia,Sportage
Green,Ford,Explorer
Black,Ford,F-150
```

Result:

```
Kia.csv

Red,Kia,Spectra
Orange,Kia,Sportage
___________________
Ford.csv

Green,Ford,Explorer
Black,Ford,F-150
```

My desired output:

```
Kia.csv

Color,Car,Make
Red,Kia,Spectra
Orange,Kia,Sportage
___________________
Ford.csv

Color,Car,Make
Green,Ford,Explorer
Black,Ford,F-150
```

To attempt getting the header column passed to the new files, I attempted something like this `awk -F'|' 'FNR==1{hdr=$0;next} {if (!seen[$1]++) print hdr>$2; print>$2}' example.csv` but unfortunately this did not have the intended result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Would you please try:

```
awk -F, '
    FNR==1 {header = $0; next}
    !seen[$2]++ {print header > $2".csv"}
    {print > $2".csv"}
' example.csv
```

If you have many varieties of car makes, "too many open files error" may occur. In such cases, please close files referring @RavinderSingh13's answer.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F, '
FNR==NR{
  header=$0
  next
}
{
  outputFile=$2".csv"
}
prev!=$2".csv" || !prev{
  close(prev)
  print header > (outputFile)
}
{
  print $0 > (outputFile)
  prev=outputFile
}
' <(head -1 Input_file) <(tail -n +2 Input_file | sort -t, -k2)
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding solution with only 1 pass of reading Input_file.

```
awk -F, -v header=$(head -1 Input_file) '
{
  outputFile=$2".csv"
}
prev!=$2".csv" || !prev{
  close(prev)
  print header > (outputFile)
}
{
  print $0 > (outputFile)
  prev=outputFile
}
' <(tail -n +2 Input_file | sort -t, -k2)
```

Comment: It is a good idea (and is mandatory in most cases) to close files to avoid `too many open files error`.